# How To Track If Tab Screen Is Active

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a tab navigator and added an Icon to each screen. I am trying to change the color of the icon associated with the screen if that screen is active. For example, when the "Live" Screen is active, I want its icon to change its color to orange. When it is inactive, it goes to white.

```
  render() { 
return ( 
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: () => {
        if (route.name === 'Online') {
            return <OnlineIcon name={'live-tv'} color= {'white'} size={35} />
        } else if (route.name === 'Live') {
            return <LiveIcon name={'basketball-ball'} color= {'white'} size={35} />
        } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            return <ProfileIcon name={'person'} color= {'white'} size={35} />
        }
      },
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: '#ff7f00',
      inactiveTintColor: 'white',
      style:{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 15, padding: 10}
  }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Online" component= {OnlineScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Live" component={LiveScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );}}
```

perhaps there is a prop that I can use with Tab.screen to check if it is active?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
render() { 
  return ( 
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#ff7f00',
          inactiveTintColor: 'white',
          style:{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 15, padding: 10}
      }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Online"
          component= {OnlineScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <OnlineIcon name={'live-tv'} color= {focused ? 'orange' : 'white'} size={35} />
            )
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Live"
          component={LiveScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <LiveIcon name={'basketball-ball'} color= {focused ? 'orange' : 'white'} size={35} />
            )
          }}
        />
        ...
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```